# Linear Combination of some vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Sorry for my newbish ways but i don't know how to write out everything here yet so bare with me.

The question asks to write some vector in $S$ as a linear combination of the others.

the vectors are:

$v1 = [0,0,0]$

$v2 = [-2,3,-4]$

$v3 = [4,-3,2]$

i got the reduced row echelon form which is

\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}

So what do i do from here? Is $x_1$ a free variable or just 0 or is $x_2$ a free variable?

I honestly have no idea where to start due to all the $x_1$'s being 0.

Comment: Yep! v1 is = [0,0,0]

Comment: x1 is a free variable. x2 isn't. Try to write the solution set now.

Comment: How about this: $[0,0,0] = 0[-2,3,-4]+0[4,-3,2]$.  Thus $[0,0,0]$ is a linear combination of the other two vectors.

Comment: But isnt it linearly dependent so that means it would be [1,0,0]?

Comment: What does $[1,0,0]$ mean?  If the question is asking you to express one vector as a linear combination of the others, then that's what I did: $[0,0,0] = 0\cdot [-2,3,-4]+0\cdot [4,-3,2]$.  You don't need to solve a matrix equation to it in this case, because it's easy to see.  If you do solve the matrix equation, you'll likely end up with $x_1$ is free, $x_2=x_3=0$, in which case it's just telling you that $k\cdot [0,0,0]+0\cdot [-2,3,-4]+0\cdot [4,-3,2]=[0,0,0]$.  But set $k=1$ and move the other two vectors to the other side and you'll have what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Let us name these vectors as **X, Y** and **Z** respectively where **X** is the zero vector. Since one of the given vectors is a zero vector, they are certainly dependent and one can be written as a linear combination of the two others. One way to do this is:
      **kX=0Y+0Z** where k is any real.

Answer (score 0):

By applying elementary row operations on your reduced row echelon form you will have the matrix:

\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}

Note that the first row have no leading 1, this means that $x_1$ is a free variable. So you are correct.

Knowing $x_1$ a free variable, you can now solve for the solution set of your equations.

Comment: So is the answer simply [1,0,0]???

Comment: Or just [0,0,0]=0[−2,3,−4]+0[4,−3,2]?